# joint two tables sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, compilation

I am new to sqlite3, need your help to join these two table, I need to joint the team id between a coach and the teams table, but when compiling it tells me that there is a problem with teamID in the coach table.
Any idea where is my mistake?

```
def creationTeamDB():
   with sqlite3.connect("teams.db") as db1:
   cursor = db1.cursor()

   cursor.execute('''
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team (
   teamID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   teamName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
   )
   ''')

def creationCoachDB():
   with sqlite3.connect("coachs.db") as db2:
   cursor = db2.cursor()

   cursor.execute('''
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coach (
   coachID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   coachName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
   teamID INTEGER
   )
   ''')
```

Thanks in advance, :)
G.B

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the comma in the second query

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coach (
   coachID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   coachName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   teamID INTEGER
   )
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found my mistake too, I am ashamed